# each function on JS array ? ( one line )?

Tags: jquery

```
<p class="a b c d"> </p>
```

How can I iterate ( **in one line**) through each class which is given me by the split func ?

I tried this :

### edit ( sorry )

```
  $("p").attr("class").split(' ').each (function (i,n){alert(n)});
```

no success...

why this line aint working ? How can I convert the array into $ array ?

Comment: `$.each($("p").attr("class").split(' '), function() { alert(this); });` [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GzPmT/). What error are you receiving?

Comment: You sure? YOUR CODE seems to be working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/aQDQr/

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me!

Comment: @techfoobar Ive edited the question sorry.

Comment: If you don't care about < ES5, you can use `.forEach` instead. You can also add a shim to make it work on older browsers (see sugar.J's)

Comment: Also, if you did get a working code (the first one you posted)... why not just use it?

Comment: @shesek learning the other options is very important

Comment: And... why are you assigning that into a variable? What are you expecting each to return? I think you might be looking for map instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$($("p").attr("class").split(' ')).each(function (i,n){alert(n);});
```

The each method only exists on jQuery objects, and split returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is not the same thing as [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The latter can be used with any iterable, but the former requires a jQuery object.

Since [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) returns an array and not a jQuery object, you should use `$.each()` instead of `each()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$($("p").attr("class").split(' ')).each (function (i,n){alert(n)});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is corret. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/3AWA6/. 
So there are two possibilities:

- have you included jQuery?
- Are you executing this command after the DOM is ready?Try this

  ```
  $(function() {$.each($("p").attr("class").split(' '),function (i,n){alert(n)})});
  ```

Comment: @RoyiNamir you can't call .each() on an array, you must call it on a jQuery object. The first version of your code was correct.